# Is there a way in ElasticSearch to get the shortest (closest) word at top?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the words inside my index: "Kem, Kemi, Kemah, Kemer, Kemerburgaz, Kemang, Kembs, Kemnay, Kempley, Kempsey, Kemerovo".

When i search for "Kem" i want "Kemi" to come at top because it is the closest word. (Kem + i = Kemi). But it doesn't go the way i want.

Index:

```
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 15
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
        ]
        }
    }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            },
        "type": "text",
        "similarity": "classic",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "slug": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Query:

```
{
"from" : 0, "size" : 10,
"query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
        {
        "match": {
            "name": "Kem"
        }
        }
    ],
    "should": [
        {
        "term": {
            "name.keyword": {
            "value": "Kem"            
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    }
}
}
'
```

Result:

```
{
"took" : 6,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
    "total" : 143,
    "max_score" : 20.795834,
    "hits" : [
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "lPL8Y2YBqxTX_xwrZlGc",
        "_score" : 20.795834,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c6317201",
        "name" : "Kem",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/karelya-cumhuriyeti/kem"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "se78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVFIU",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c121023",
        "name" : "Kemah",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/houston-ve-civari/kemah"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ze78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVFo5",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c1783",
        "name" : "Kemerovo",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/kemerovo-oblasti/kemerovo"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xe78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVFs9",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c1786",
        "name" : "Kemi",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/rovaniemi/kemi"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Tu78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVG-X",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c1900",
        "name" : "Kempsey",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/new-south-wales/kempsey"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Bu78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVILt",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c3000010982",
        "name" : "Kempley",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/dymock/kempley"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "B-78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVILt",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c3000010983",
        "name" : "Kemnay",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/inverurie/kemnay"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "CO78Y2YBqxTX_xwrVIb_",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c3000013079",
        "name" : "Kemerburgaz",
        "slug" : "eyup/kemerburgaz"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "-fL8Y2YBqxTX_xwrZQxf",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c6190744",
        "name" : "Kembs",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/haut-rhin-bolge/kembs"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xfL8Y2YBqxTX_xwrZSG-",
        "_score" : 8.61574,
        "_source" : {
        "id" : "c6216986",
        "name" : "Kemang",
        "slug" : "yurtdisi/cakarta/kemang"
        }
    }
    ]
}
}
```

Now they are at same score because everyone have the "Kem" i guess. But if i do "match" or "match_phrase" the outcome is the same.

Comment: You should augment your question with the actual query you're sending, it'd make it easier for people to provide hints and solutions.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, by default, a `match` query will not match `Kem` to `Kemerburgaz` unless you modify the default fuzziness, and it is indeed a fuzzy matching then: [**Fuzzy matching should not be used for scoring purposes—only to widen the net of matching terms in case there are misspellings.**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html)

Comment: Added the index/mapping for you to view. How it is a fuzzy matching? I didn't specify any fuzziness.

Comment: You're using the ngram filter (important information you originally omitted by the way). This will basically create an ngram of each word, meaning that when you match `Kem` you are actually matching the `Kem` part of the ngram, which all terms which start with Kem will have. There's no extra scoring for this because the matches are equivalent. The index doesn't actually know what the original word was, all it knows is that there's between 2-15 words for each indexed word. `Kem` is scored first because it also matches the `term` filter

Comment: What should i use then? I am using edge-ngram because I am using autocomplete. What will change in different examples? What will give extra scores for closest word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it seems that you want your results sorted by length. You can do that with a script.

```
POST your_index/_doc/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Kem"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": {
              "value": "Kem"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {"order": "desc"}
    },
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "doc['name.keyword'].value.length()",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "name.keyword": {"order": "asc"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: According to your error, it looks like you are missing single quotes. `"script" : "doc[name.keyword].value.length()"` should be `"script" : "doc['name.keyword'].value.length()"`.

Comment: Single quotes are not at the error. But they are at there when i execute it. Just copied your text.

Comment: It may have copied odd characters? Trying removing them and typing them manually. I can duplicate your error if I remove the single quote, but they go away when I add them back in.

Comment: Tim there is no error at copying. I triple checked it. Maybe you have different ElasticSearch version? I am using 6.4. Similar error with no answer is here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47566393/painless-scripting-elastic-search-variable-is-not-defined-error-when-trying-to

Comment: Ah i see now. Like here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/doc-variable-not-defined-in-painless-script/132136 It is because of using curl on console and that quotes. What are you using to post that?

Comment: I’m using the Dev tool in Kibana

Comment: Escaping it like doc[\"name.keyword\"] works on terminal curl.